# Select box with Array values into PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this. Getting this value in $_POST

```
Array ( [emp_box] => Array ( [0] => 31_11_8 [1] => 31_12_1 [2] => 56_11_1 [3] => 56_12_1 [4] => 66_11_1 [5] => 66_12_1 [6] => 71_11_1 [7] => 71_12_1 [8] => 72_11_1 [9] => 72_12_1 ) [submit] => Add )
```

Now I want the above array to be stored in my DB tables(TB Name: rating_list).

```
Author_ID       Book_ID     Rating
==================================
31              11          8
31              12          1
56              11          1
56              12          1

...............
```

How can I achieve this. I'm not into PHP array and I'm at the beginning stage.
So some-one could help me out
Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($emp_box as $key=>$val)
    {
        $val2=explode("_",$val);

        $query="insert into rating_list (Author_ID ,Book_ID , Rating) values ('".$val2[0]."','".$val2[1]."','".$val2[2]."')";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PDO to access mysql

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO rating_list (Author_ID, Book_ID, Rating)
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
foreach ($_POST['emp_box'] as $emp) {
    $stmt->execute(exploe('_', $emp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this. Hope it helps

```
    $insertArray = $_POST['emp_box'];
    foreach($insertArray as $iArr){
      $vals = explode("_",$iArr);
      $author_id = $iArr[0];
      $book_id = $iArr[1];
      $rating = $iArr[2];
      //than execute your insert query for database here.
    }
```